# Swap values of keys in JSON array

Tags: javascript

I have the following JSON. I need to swap SortId

Like I have this,

```
[{"CategoryId":1,"Name":"Worktable","SortId":1}
,{"CategoryId":2,"Name":"Bf ","SortId":2}]
```

After swaping their 'SortId' I need

```
[{"CategoryId":1,"Name":"Worktable","SortId":2}
,{"CategoryId":2,"Name":"Bf ","SortId":1}]
```

Please tell me how to do it through JavaScript.

Comment: If you want to do this in JavaScript, then this has nothing to do with JSON. You are basically asking how to switch the property values of two objects.

Comment: was your first idea is to ask or provide a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
var tmp = a[0].SortId;
a[0].SortId = a[1].SortId;
a[1].SortId = tmp;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4U3g/)